# How to change the Customer new account email

Tags: email

I would like to change the "Customer new account" email.

In this line:

```php
<p><?php printf( __( 'Thanks for creating an account on %1$s. Your username is %2$s', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $blogname ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user_login ) . '</strong>' ); ?></p>
```

I would like to change the parameter %2$s, instead of showing the username I would like to show the email address.

What parameter should I use to show the email address?

This is the complete customer-new-account.php :

```php
<?php
/**
 * Customer new account email
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-new-account.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

    <p><?php printf( __( 'Thanks for creating an account on %1$s. Your username is %2$s', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $blogname ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user_login ) . '</strong>' ); ?></p>

<?php if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) && $password_generated ) : ?>

    <p><?php printf( __( 'Your password has been automatically generated: %s', 'woocommerce' ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user_pass ) . '</strong>' ); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>

    <p><?php printf( __( 'You can access your account area to view your orders and change your password here: %s.', 'woocommerce' ), make_clickable( esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) ) ); ?></p>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

Thanks for the support!

Comment: Format your question properly, please.

Comment: How are people supposed to know that you are talking about WooCommerce?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest one is to copy the mail template to your theme folder into `path/to/your/theme/woocommerce/emails/customer-new-account.php` and adjust the argument from `user_login` to `user_email`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session variable.

For example,

- start session in functions.php
- After submitting my account form store user email in that session variable.
- Display session variable in the alert box & unset within same page.

Answer (score 0):

**$user_email** variable is accessible inside Customer new account email template.
[Class WC_Email_Customer_New_Account file](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-emails-class-wc-email-customer-new-account.html#source-view.38)